# configure ghc-mod for atom on ubuntu

Tags: atom-editor, ghc-mod

If I install ghc-mod with

```
cabal install ghc-mod
```

I get:

```
$ ghc-mod --version
ghc-mod version 5.5.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.6.3
```

However, atom complains

> Haskell-ghc-mod: ghc-mod failed to launch it is probably missing or
>   misconfigured
>
> ```
> Error: spawnSync ghc-mod ENOENT
> ```

However, as I am on ubuntu, `sudo apt-get ghc-mod` fixes the problem but atom this time complains that

> Error: Command failed: ghc-mod version "version" not supported ghc-mod
>   version 3.1.4

It seems therefore the case that `apt-get` installs the wrong version of ghc-mod the right way while `cabal` installs the right version of ghc-mod the wrong way.

tried `sudo cabal install ghc-mod --global` with no success

> Error: Command failed: ghc-mod version "version" not supported ghc-mod
>   version 3.1.4